# Why was my close vote removed and comment deleted?

Tags: support

I voted to close [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959193/create-qr-code-in-ubuntu-16-04) as a duplicate but on returning to it, I find my vote removed and comment deleted.

I guess it was removed by a moderator but why?

Currently, I feel this is very much suppressing my right to vote to close the question, perhaps I am wrong about the dupe but that does not give someone the right to suppress my vote and remove my comment.

I would like to know, who removed it and why, I am very confused by this, am I missing something? this seems odd and out of character for the mods here.

Comment: Go to chat and you'll see.

Comment: Are you talking about the comment that was automatically posted in your name when you cast your duplicate close vote?

Comment: @EliahKagan Yes but oli has explained it below, it was me not thinking it through, I am glad it was not just removed by someone who dissagrred.

Comment: No worries, the Stack Exchange system can be confusing, especially when multiple separate events take place in a short time. I think this is a useful question to have on meta for the benefit of other readers who may have similar concerns.

Comment: Related (on [Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)): [Why did my close vote vanish?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359626/why-did-my-close-vote-vanish)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was closed. That deletes the automated "I think this is a duplicate of ..." comment. Your vote counted towards the closure.

Then it was reopened by other people.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I see now, it happend so fast I did not think about that.

Comment: @MarkKirby I recommend always checking [the revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/959193/revisions) before jumping to conclusions ;)

Answer (score 5):

The question was reopened by five community votes. To address what I think is one of your concerns: your vote has not been suppressed or forgotten. **It remains viewable** in the post's [revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/959193/revisions) and in its [timeline](https://askubuntu.com/posts/959193/timeline). Both pages are publicly available, even to users who are not logged into the site.

If your comment was automatically posted for you when you voted to close the question, then it was removed when the question was closed, [as Oli says](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17315/22949). Thus the automatic removal of the comment and the reopening of the question were two separate events, which happened to occur with only a short time window in between.

Even though you probably cannot immediately vote to reclose that question--since you had already voted to do so--**you can still manually post a new comment** indicating that the questions are related, or even making the case that they should be duplicated once again. If no other comment on the post expresses that information, then I would suggest you consider doing so (even though I was one of the reopen voters, so it is possible I might not personally agree with what you might say).